# Exception after .net 6 upgrade

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, .net-6.0

The following code (which worked fine in .net core 3.1)

```
var jobType = AppDomain.CurrentDomain
.GetAssemblies()
.SelectMany(x => x.DefinedTypes)
.Single(x => x.FullName == className);
```

is throwing the exception after the upgrade to .net 6
[image]

`className` is the namespace to a class we need to dynamically instantiate
my.redacted.namespace.Jobs.ReminderMail.MonthlyUpdateReminderJob

Is this way of dynamically getting the `Type` not possible anymore and what would be the way to go?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you upgrade also relevant packages to get Net6 support? Like [Microsoft.Build](https://github.com/dotnet/msbuild) for example?

Comment: Are you running VS2022? VS2019 is not (fully) compatible with .NET 6.0.

Comment: Microsoft.Build is not referenced in the solution...

Comment: @PMF yes I'm running VS 2022

Comment: Microsoft.Build is an implicit reference of the build system. But it should use Version 16.9 for .NET 6.0 I think (at least certainly something > 16)

Comment: hmm interesting, when I added the nuget Microsoft.Build to the project it works again :S